# How to edit array to add keynames, from a httpclient api call in MVC?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I am very new to MVC and making api calls server side and need a little guidance.  I have created a simple method to call an api to retrieve results in a JSON object:

apiController.cs (normal controller.cs file)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult getDefaultStuff(string a = "abc") {
 var url = "https://myapiurl";
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Blah");
 var response = client.GetStringAsync(url);
 return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The results return in an array like this:

```
{Result: {examples: [[0000,6.121],[0000,1.122],[0000,9.172]]},"Id":81,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}
```

I need it to return with keynames like this :

```
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "Keyname1": "45678",
      "Keyname2": "1234"
    },
    {
      "Keyname1": "14789",
      "Keyname2": "1234"
    },
    {
      "Keyname1": "12358",
      "Keyname2": "4569"
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I need to use IDictonary? I am unsure of the approach. Do I create a new object and then loop through each result adding keynames? an example would be much appreciated or just the approach will be very helpful.

Comment: The response you've listed as what you want isn't valid JSON. The `[]` per item should be `{}`. Also property names should be quoted.

Comment: sorry I have edited the code to show full result. I need to edit this result?

Comment: 1) Upload your desired JSON to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see errors.  Can you [edit] your question to show a sample of desired JSON that is valid?  2) What version of [asp.net-mvc] are you using?  Different versions use different serializers.

Comment: Thank you, I know the error's it's returning [ ] instead of " " im using mvc 5. My question is how do I edit the response. I will edit now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

By using the [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) nuget package first deserialize the response into, for example, an anonymous object:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response, new
{
    examples = new[] { new decimal[] { } }
});
```

Then transform this object into the new one that has the property structure you need:

```
var result = new
{
    examples = deserialized.Result.examples.Select(x => new
    {
        Keyname1 = x[0],
        Keyname2 = x[1]
    })
};
```

And return it to the client:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is what your solution could roughly look like but you do have to keep several things in mind though:

1. Exception handling for deserialization
2. Checks for possible nulls in the deserialized object
3. Maybe also the safer way of retrieving values from the array to avoid possible out of range exceptions.

Also the `GetStringAsync` method is asynchronous and you should put an `await` keyword in front of it, but in order to do so you need to make your method `async` as well:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getDefaultStuff(...)
```

If you don't have enough knowledge of asynchronous programming, [here](https://www.wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch/performing-i-o-bound-asynchronous-operations?videoId=performing-i-o-bound-asynchronous-operations) is the most advanced, in-depth and comprehensive video explaining it from top to bottom I have ever seen, so check it out whenever you find time...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Forgive me but at what point do I pass the response? I.e var response = client.GetStringAsync(url);

Comment: Thank you for link I will be sure to swot up - really need to know this!!

Comment: Oh sorry, I've made an edit so you can see where the `response` variable should be passed. It's right on the first line of code...

Comment: Haha I realised this after going through  it that the response passed there :)

Comment: I'm getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on var result = new - do I set initial value further up?

Comment: Which variable is null? `deserialized` or `deserialized.Result`?

Comment: Seems to be deserialized. When I debug response does have value

Comment: That probably means that the json you have provided is somehow different from the one that `GetStringAsync` method returns. Can you share exactly what that string is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127016/discussion-between-gwynbleidd-and-user3515765).

Comment: No no it wasn't the issue. I removed  Result = new - when I debugged the array returning didn't have result and it's worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help,link and time , you have saved the day :)